# How to Zoom a UIImageView that fills the screen

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uiimage, zooming

I'm simply trying to zoom a photo I have set on a UIImageView that is on a UIScrollView.  Perhaps it's because the image is the same size as the screen but in my code below neither `viewForZoomingInScrollView` nor `scrollViewDidZoom` are called.  Please help me fix this so I can zoom around the image.  Thanks:

Interface:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIScrollView* scrollView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *imageHolder;

@end
```

Implementation:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

// Tell the scroll view the size of the contents
self.scrollView.contentSize = self.view.frame.size;

self.scrollView.delegate = self;
self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;

_imageHolder = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
_scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];

[self.imageHolder setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"P1020486.png"]];

[self.scrollView addSubview:_imageHolder];
[self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];

//Keep the proportion and fit the screen, not filling it --> when we rotate, resizes image correctly:
_imageHolder.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

// Set up the minimum & maximum zoom scales
CGRect scrollViewFrame = self.scrollView.frame;
CGFloat scaleWidth = scrollViewFrame.size.width / self.scrollView.contentSize.width;
CGFloat scaleHeight = scrollViewFrame.size.height / self.scrollView.contentSize.height;
CGFloat minScale = MIN(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
//
self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = minScale;
self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1.0f;

[self centerScrollViewContents];
}

- (void)centerScrollViewContents {
CGSize boundsSize = self.scrollView.bounds.size;
CGRect contentsFrame = self.imageHolder.frame;

if (contentsFrame.size.width < boundsSize.width) {
    contentsFrame.origin.x = (boundsSize.width - contentsFrame.size.width) / 2.0f;
} else {
    contentsFrame.origin.x = 0.0f;
}

if (contentsFrame.size.height < boundsSize.height) {
    contentsFrame.origin.y = (boundsSize.height - contentsFrame.size.height) / 2.0f;
} else {
    contentsFrame.origin.y = 0.0f;
}

self.imageHolder.frame = contentsFrame;
}

#pragma mark - UIScrollViewDelegate

- (UIView*)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
// Return the view that we want to zoom
return self.imageHolder;
//return self.scrollViewBar;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
// The scroll view has zoomed, so we need to re-center the contents
[self centerScrollViewContents];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at your code real quick, it looks like you're setting properties on the scrollView before you've initialized it:

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = self.view.frame.size;

self.scrollView.delegate = self;

self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;

_scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
```

If you reverse the order, it should work.

Comment: Yes!  Thanks so much.  That was very stupid of me but there we go.  Now it works.  Cheers

Answer (score 3):

I have no time to test it, but I think that problem is this line:

```
self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1.0f;
```

Try to put there 2.0f or something bigger.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Your advice seems logical but sadly it still won't zoom.

Comment: Hi Alois, Although CodeBySteveZ's answer below solved it for me, your answer was also part of the solution as `1.0f` was no good.  Thanks again.